Number of impressions on AdMob Panel and actual rewarded ads doesn't match
I have implemented AdMob Server Side Verification  How to verify Admob Rewarded Video Ad on a server?
Everytime the user finishes watcing a rewarded ad, Google Server Makes a GET call to my Server. I verify the signature, then store an entry to my database.
To my surprise, I noticed a discrepancy between the number of API calls recorded and the impression count on the AdMob Panel.
This results in lesser earning than what I actually reward my user.
Server Logs:
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-07-31 00:00:00.000Z: 2
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-01 00:00:00.000Z: 3
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-02 00:00:00.000Z: 1
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-03 00:00:00.000Z: 2
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-04 00:00:00.000Z: 35
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-06 00:00:00.000Z: 6
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-07 00:00:00.000Z: 3
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-08 00:00:00.000Z: 5
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-09 00:00:00.000Z: 36
ad_reward_audit.dart:52:7) 2024-08-10 00:00:00.000Z: 28

AdMob Panel:

Am I wrong to think that the number of impression should match the number SSV API call ?
If it should be the case, what other steps can I do to investigate this ? I am making loss at the moment do this issue as my rewards to user actually cost me actual money  (Computing time cost on expensive GPU)
